# not able to use DISTINCT or group by keyword in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

This is my `controller.php`:

```
$courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered.course_id',array('isactive'=>'1'));
```

This is my `Model.php`:

```
function get_data_wheree($table,$where)
{
  return $this->db->group_by($table,$where)->result();
}
```

In my `model.php` I want to use DISTINCT OR GROUP_BY in the Query.

The `group_by` is not working properly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a few minutes to read [ask], and then improve your question by editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not working because the `result()` method is a member of the class `CI_DB_result` but `group_by()` returns an instance of `CI_DB_query_builder`. In other words, you are trying to call a method that does not exist for the class being used.

The methods `get()` and `get_where()` are the only two Query Builder methods that return a `CI_DB_result` object. Put simply, you have to call `get()` or `get_where()` before you can use `result()` or any similar methods.

The other problem is that `group_by()` does not take a second argument of the type you provide. You're providing an array but it expects a boolean. You need to add another method to define a where condition.

Your model's method should look like the following. 
I changed the name of the first argument to better describe its purpose.

```
function get_data_where($groupby, $where)
{
  return $this->db
         ->group_by($groupby)
         ->where($where)
         ->get('tbl_course_offered')
         ->result();
}
```